# Detecting all links in markdown files in python and replace them with outputs of string function

Tags: python-3.x, markdown, python-re

I have a python function `f(foo: string) -> string`. I don't write the details of the function because it could be change.

I need to get *all* links from markdown file and replace them with the result of that function.

Example: this links

```
This is  a text and this [is first link](http://example.com "Example Title") and
 this [is a second](#example) link.
```

would replace as

```
This is  a text and this [is first link](result1 "Example Title") and
 this [is a second](result2) link.
```

where `f(http://example.com)=result1` and `f(#example)=result2`. That is `result1` is the output of `f(http://example.com)` and `result2` is the output of `f(#example)`.

Can we do in python regular expressions or with some specific package which traits markdown files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying [mreinhart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30738268/2755116) response to this question, this could be done:

```
def find_md_links(md):
    """Returns dict of links in markdown:
    'regular': [foo](some.url)
    'footnotes': [foo][3]
    
    [3]: some.url
    """
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/30738268/2755116

    INLINE_LINK_RE = re.compile(r'\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)')
    FOOTNOTE_LINK_TEXT_RE = re.compile(r'\[([^\]]+)\]\[(\d+)\]')
    FOOTNOTE_LINK_URL_RE = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\]:\s+(\S+)')

    links = list(INLINE_LINK_RE.findall(md))
    footnote_links = dict(FOOTNOTE_LINK_TEXT_RE.findall(md))
    footnote_urls = dict(FOOTNOTE_LINK_URL_RE.findall(md))

    footnotes_linking = []
        
    for key in footnote_links.keys():
        footnotes_linking.append((footnote_links[key], footnote_urls[footnote_links[key]]))

    return {'regular': links, 'footnotes': footnotes_linking}


def replace_md_links(md, f):
    """Replace links url to f(url)"""
    
    links = find_md_links(md)
    newmd = md

    for r in links['regular']:
        newmd = newmd.replace(r[1], f(r[1]))

    for r in links['footnotes']:
        newmd = newmd.replace(r[1], f(r[1]))
    
    return newmd
```

`f` is a function. For example, I use this function which only changes links which belong from `#` in `replace_md_links`

```
def mychange(s, prefix="/static/entrades/", suffix=".md.html"):
    """Change links from tiddlywiki syntax [foo](#something) to [foo](prefix + something + suffix)"""
    
    if s.startswith('#'):
        return prefix + slugify.slugify(urllib.parse.unquote( s.replace('#', '', 1) )) + suffix
    else:
        return s
```